# How to print a string and its characters' positions?

Tags: javascript

To accelerate my debugging process, I need a way to print a string with its characters' positions below it:

```js
a string with its characters' positions below it
0 2 4 6 8 0 2 4 6 8 0 2 4 6 8 0 2 4 6 8 0 2 4 6 8
          1         2         3         4
```

My solution is simple:

```js
console.debug(`%c${string}`, 'background-color: yellow');
console.debug(`0 2 4 6 8 0 2 4 6 8 0 2 4 6 8 0`);
console.debug(`          1         2         3`);
```

But since the string's length varies, it would be nice to match the ruler's length with its length too.

Comment: You can destructure steering into an array: `console.debug([...string])`, which would give you different results visually, but would help you debut the string

Comment: So make a string of digits based on `string.length`? What exactly is the question?

Comment: @Pointy hmm, I guess I can do it with a for and if, but I want to take a look if there are other solutions that brings new perspectives

Comment: @Ooker can you show us what you tried to solve this in the general case?

Comment: @M0nst3R I haven't worked out the idea yet, but given the purpose is to look for better solutions, I guess my try is not important anyway? I guess that solution is a module specifying on strings or decorations or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to create functions that generate the positions on the fly based on the length of the string in question.

The snippet below showcases an example solution where we have three functions:

- `getUnits()` generates the units of the positions as you laid out.
- `getTens()` generates the tens of the positions as you laid out.
- `getDebugString()` generates the entire debug string by combining the previous.

```js
function getUnits(length) {
    let string = '';
    for (let i = 0; i <= length; i++)
        string += i % 2 ? ' ' : i % 10;
    return string;
}
function getTens(length) {
    let string = '';
    for (let i = 0; i <= length; i++)
        string += i % 10 ? ' ' : Math.floor(i / 10);
    return string;
}
function getDebugString(string) {
    return `${string}\n${getUnits(string.length)}\n${getTens(string.length)}`;
}

console.log(getDebugString(`a string`));
console.log(getDebugString(`a string with its characters`));
console.log(getDebugString(`a string with its characters' positions below it`));
```